# Android Wear 2.0 styled switches

Tags: material-design, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I'm making a watch face for my android wear watch and in the config activity I want a switch. The switch looks like a usual android switch ([picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7Hb9.png)) but I want it to look like the new switchs in android wear 2.0 ([picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsE0f.png)). How did google do them?

Comment: Great question. Just to let you know your image links are missing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The switch in picture 2 is a [SwitchPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/SwitchPreference.html) which is (at least currently) only supported in a [PreferenceFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html).

Comment: Ok thanks, but I hope they will add it as RoundSwitch or something like that.

Comment: Is there any samples of this available?

Comment: Yeah I really hope so too! Not sure if there's an example specifically for the SwitchPreference. There's a pretty good example for PreferenceFragment in general (link in the answer) and you should be able to simply swap out one of the items for a SwitchPreference. Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

In the latest update we added a RoundSwitch style which should do exactly what you need.

See here:
[Support Library Wear R.style](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/R.style.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Widget.Wear.RoundSwitch` style to get the round switch style.

Here is an example:

```xml
<Switch
    style="@style/Widget.Wear.RoundSwitch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```